# How to understand $\limsup$/$\liminf$ of a subset of a complete lattice with a topology

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_a_set):

> Let $Y$ be a partially ordered set which is also a topological space and a complete
>   lattice so that the suprema and infima always exist. For a set $X ⊆
>  Y$, define $$
>      \liminf X := \inf \{ x \in Y : x \text{ is a limit point of } X \}\, $$ 
>   $$
>      \limsup X := \sup \{ x \in Y : x \text{ is a limit point of } X \}\, $$

I wonder if this definition is consistent in some way with the informal interpretation of $\limsup$ as $\inf \sup$, and of $\liminf$ as $\sup \inf$, or just another case that you "don't know why Wikipedia writes what it writes"? 
Thanks!